# Powershell ISE Ver 4 script pane left side?

Tags: powershell

Is there a way that I can change script pane to left side in Powershell ISE V4?

The default layout for script pane are top or right side.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so... The only options in the View Menu are `CTRL + 1` (View on Top) `CTRL + 2` (View on Right) and `CTRL + 3` (View Maximized).

Answer (score 0):

For a workarround I'm opening 2 windows - one for ISE and I move it to the left and the second one as a normal ps command window and place it on the right...